# How do I reset an HTML5 table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in HTML written as such:

```html
    <table id="spreadsheet" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th id="spreadsheet-year">2015</th>
       <th>Month (Est)</th>
       <th>Month (Act)</th>
       <th>YTD (Est)</th>
       <th>YTD (Act)</th>
       <th>Full Year (Est)</th>
       <th>Full Year (Act)</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Jan</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Feb</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Mar</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Apr</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
      </tr>
             ...
             ...
             ...
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

I use [this script](https://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/) to make the table interactive. It works quite nicely, but I'm wondering how I'd go about resetting the table after the modal is submitted or closed? Otherwise the same values will persist when the user opens the modal again.

Comment: this `$("td").val("0");` ? If you want for specific cells then add a class say, class="resetCellClass" then `$(".resetCellClass").val("0");`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way would be to clone it before editing it but after plugin initialization:

```
var $defaultTable = $('#spreadsheet').clone(true);
```

Then whenever you need to reset it, use:

```
$('#spreadsheet').replaceWith($defaultTable);
```

**EDIT** To handle multiple reseting, you need to clone it when replacing it too in order to not work on futur edited copy, e.g:

```
$('#spreadsheet').replaceWith($defaultTable.clone(true));
```

Comment: You are awesome! There is no standard method provided in doc so this seems to be the only option...

Comment: Wow, using `clone()` is quite a nifty way to do it! (If it were me, I would probably loop through and clear each value)

Comment: Thank you very much. Very elegant solution!